# Accuracy with auto arima

Tags: r, arima

This dataset contains data about Store 1 and Store 2 from 2014 until 2019. So my intention is to make projections with the forecast package and Snaive function simultaneously for both sales. So below you can see the function for that forecast

```
my_data_input<-data.frame( 
      Store1=rnorm(72, mean=900, sd=450),
      Store2=rnorm(72, mean=700, sd=400))
    
    
    my_data<-ts(my_data_input,start=c(2012,1),end=c(2017,11),frequency = 12) 
    
    forecast_horizon<-13 # Forecast horizont
    seasons<-as.numeric(12)
    year_start=2012
    
    
    train<-window(my_data, start = 2012, end = 2015)
    test<-window(my_data, start = 2016, end = 2017)
    
    
    arima_function <- function(Z, forecast_horizon = forecast_horizon) {
      timeseries <- msts(Z, start = year_start, seasonal.periods = seasons)
      forecast <- auto.arima(timeseries)
    }
    
    
    forcasting_arima_list <- lapply(X = train, arima_function)
```

This function works well and now I want to see the model's accuracy separate for the train and separate for the test set. I tried with the function from the Forecast package and also I add my previous function but is not work.

```
accuracy(forecast(forcasting_arima_list,h=13),x=test)
```

So can anybody help me how to solve this problem? In the end, I need to receive output in format describe below (not figures,only format)

```
                           ME      RMSE       MAE          MPE       MAPE      MASE      ACF1 Theil's U
    Training set  0.009771848 0.2770957 0.2220807  0.002654923 0.06701084 0.1795918 0.1124374        NA
    Test set     -0.980333471 1.1563839 1.0294249 -0.273341488 0.28703793 0.8324733 0.8381198 0.8725192

                       ME      RMSE       MAE          MPE       MAPE      MASE      ACF1 Theil's U
Training set  0.009771848 0.2770957 0.2220807  0.002654923 0.06701084 0.1795918 0.1124374        NA
Test set     -0.980333471 1.1563839 1.0294249 -0.273341488 0.28703793 0.8324733 0.8381198 0.8725192
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a nice evolution of the [forecast package](https://otexts.com/fpp3/) (tsibble and fable) that plays well with the tidyverse and allows grouping, e.g. of the stores. Accuracy included in the example below using your data:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(fpp3)

my_data_input <- data.frame(
  Store1 = rnorm(72, mean = 900, sd = 450),
  Store2 = rnorm(72, mean = 700, sd = 400)
)

store_ts <- my_data_input |> 
  mutate(month = yearmonth("2012-1") |> 
           seq(length.out = 72, by = 1)) |> 
  pivot_longer(starts_with("Store")) |> 
  as_tsibble(key = name, index = month) 

train_ts <- store_ts |> 
  filter(year(month) <= 2015)

test_ts <- store_ts |> 
  filter(year(month) > 2015)

train_fc <- train_ts |> 
  model(ARIMA = ARIMA(value)) |> 
  forecast(h = 13)

train_fc |> 
  autoplot(store_ts)
```

[image]

```r
accuracy(train_fc, test_ts)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 11
#>   .model name   .type    ME  RMSE   MAE    MPE  MAPE  MASE RMSSE    ACF1
#>   <chr>  <chr>  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 ARIMA  Store1 Test  282.   486.  447.  -5.96  61.4   NaN   NaN -0.316 
#> 2 ARIMA  Store2 Test  -38.0  266.  214. -24.3   41.3   NaN   NaN -0.0832
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>